# Copy a Domain account from an old hdd to a new installation on the same laptop

Tags: hard-drive, vpn, domain, migration

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate that is on a Domain and I have had problems with installed software which has caused some corruption to two of my software systems, they don't play nicely together. I work overseas and not in the office and we don't have an IT person in the office so its not easy trying to get support, I can access the Domain via VPN

I have purchased a new drive and reinstalled all the software I need on it, I have also installed the VPN link and can access the Domain, even though I am not a Domain user on this installation.

Can I transfer my old credentials from my old hdd to the new installation, I did try to rejoin the domain manually but I lost all Admin rights after doing it that way, so is it possible to copy from one hdd to another, just the domain accounts which has admin rights to it

I have tried Windows Easy Transfer but that requires you to be on the Domain, even though i am connected via VPN it still says I need to be on the Domain

Answer (score 0):

If the old HDD/computer was on the domain, you'll need to connect the computer back to the domain in order to get the policies. You could use the local GPEdit to approximate many of the settings, but the trust relationship that the VPN relies on is only going to work if you actually add the computer back to the domain.

The way your computer was probably set up previously was that it was joined to the domain, and then a local user account was created for you. So the computer had a trust relationship with the domain and could connect to it, and you could work outside most of the domain restrictions.

You'll need to follow the same process to get your settings back the way they were, and not you, but the company IT people will have to be the ones to do it due to the rights required to perform these actions.